# How do I respond to a response?

Tags: support, comments

When I ask a question, then obtain a question in response, how do I enter and respond to the question?

Comment: You should write a comment. That's that text field below that post. It just works below your own posts without enough reputation. Include the user you want to respond to with `@user`.

Comment: You add comments to the answer, if something is not clear.

Comment: This question should probably be moved to TeX Meta.

Comment: This is my response to your instructions. Is this correct? TeXnician@user

Comment: yes but the ping should look like @TeXnician (type `@T` and the rest of the name will be prompted)

Comment: Thanks David @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @MiltRiggs that worked:-)

Answer (score 9):

To simply put this into an answer: You should use the comment feature to respond to users or to ask for clarification. You can always comment on your own questions and answers. Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post.

If you want to mention a user in your comment you ping him with `@user`, but substitute `user` for his name. So if you want to ping me you would type `@TeXnician`.

In the comments you can use the usual markdown you can use in questions/answers (code highlighting, font adjustments etc.), but avoid putting too many important information in there. Sometimes you should edit your own question instead (or of course answer, if you found a solution).